# Django admin won't load on my local after logging in

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm new to python and django.

I've copied my production app, that another developer wrote, onto my local. It's working perfectly. When I run django admin I get the login form. But when I enter my ID and PW I get redirected to the same login form, only it's blank; I never get logged in.

The server console reads:

```
    [26/Apr/2022 06:25:21] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
    [26/Apr/2022 06:25:21] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
    [26/Apr/2022 06:25:21] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11020
```

I don't understand what's needed to change or get added. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted the issue.

I commented out SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN from my settings.py file and that solved it.